# Multiple drawables on a single ImageButton

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I need to add multiple drawables on a single ImageButton. Probably the answer is, it is not possible.

But still, any ideas on what kind of approach should I follow to implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: Make a compound view subclass from a view group (like LinearLayout), make it clickable and set its background to be the same as a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` or any other GroupView (as your need) that has button style and containes some `ImageView`s as your need.

If you need more explanation ask your question more spacific.

Comment: But I will need to click on it as a button. Can a LinearLayout with a button style provide that?

Comment: When set the LinearLayout `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` with the ImageViews inside, it solved my problem.